# How to open new tab with Existing Name,Again and Again?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I am developing Web Application

In home.jsp i am having javaScript for opening the new tab.

**Java Script**

```
var newtabWin = null;
function openNewTab(myPagePath, myPageName)
{
 newtabWin = window.open(myPagePath, myPageName); 
}

<commandLink id="newtabEntryId"
             onclick="openNewTab('./../settl/internalStatusviewer.jsp','internalStatusviewer');"            
</commandLink>
```

Once I login into Main Application as **USER 1** , I have many links that can open in new tab ,Consider I am opening the page name called **InternalStatusviewer.jsp** in new tab after some time, I have closed the **Main Application** through browser close but still new tab **InternalStatusviewer.jsp** is alive

**Here the Problem Start**
Again User 1 need to login the system where in new tab **InternalStatusviewer.jsp** location , so user reload the **InternalStatusviewer.jsp** page and logging successfully , Know user tries to open again the new tab **InternalStatusviewer.jsp.**

It's **not opening in new tab** instead of that it get load in the same tab.

** I want to load a page in new tab and it should open at one time only **

I have tried with **window.open('','_blank')**, by this I can achieve but it will open multiple new tabs

Comment: If I understood the question, you want the same user SESSION to reuse the tabs he has opened, but with another session from the same user from the same browser you want different tabs?

Comment: @EskoPiirainen yes,I need to open in different tab but it's reloading in the same tab

Answer (score 0):

The second argument of window.open takes in a tab's "windowName". You can freely define it to be any text, for example "index_user1"  or "payments_user1"  or   "index_user1_session_123".  When you give the same text, the tab will be reused. If you give a different text, a new tab will be opened.  With that info you should be able to do exactly what you want.

See for example https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open

(If you want session scope tabs, **do not** use user's real session ids in windowName)

Comment: S you are correct if we change the name of the window then we can get New Tab......Then a page can open many time so same page can access at many time right,,, I dont need this to do